# Reset current view controller when users hits home button

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a game, and if the user hits the home button I want to "reset" the current view controller to the menu instead of bringing them back into the game.

I'm guessing I can do something in `applicationWillResignActive` or `applicationDidBecomeActive` but not sure where to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `applicationWillResignActive` you can

```
let menuVC = /////

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = menuVC
```